# Valid scope name

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

File "/Users/Mohannad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2908, in name_scope
    raise ValueError("'%s' is not a valid scope name" % name)
ValueError: 'the context text' is not a valid scope name

**AnyBody know what does this mean or how to solve it ?**

Answer (score 6):

I've just fixed the same problem. Reason: space in names is not accepted.
Simply modify 'the context text' to 'the-context-text' will fix your problem.